# Composite Functions- Relation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, functions

the question is on the topic of composite functions and relations and I am struggling with it, as one of the functions is a standard function and the other one is a relation set. The question is written below with my attempt

Let   $S   = \{1, 2, 3, 4\}$ and let $f:S \to S,g:S \to S$ and $h:S \to S$ be  defined by

$f(n)=5-n$

$g(n)=3$

$h=\{(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),(4,1)\}$

Determine $f\circ h$ and $h\circ f$

$\mathbf {My Attempt}$

for $h\circ f$

so for $n=1$

$h(f(n))$

$h(f(1))$

$h(4)=1$

Therefore for the 1st ordered pair I got

$h\circ f$ =$\{(1,1)\}$

My final answer for $h\circ f$

$h\circ f$ =$\{(1,1),(2,4),(3,3),(4,2)\}$

Regarding $f\circ h$, I am struggling with that one

but I ended up with $f\circ h$ = $\{(1,4),(2,3),(3,2),(4,1)\}$

Any kind of help will be appreciated

Comment: Which is the role of $g(n)$?

Comment: To obtain $\to$, type `$\to$`.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer for $h \circ f$ is correct.  Your answer for $f \circ h$ is not.

By definition, $(f \circ h)(n) = f(h(n))$.  Thus,
\begin{align*}
(f \circ h)(1) & = f(h(1))\\
               & = f(2) && \text{since $(1, 2) \in h \implies h(1) = 2$}\\
               & = 5 - 2 && \text{since $f(n) = 5 - n$}\\
               & = 3
\end{align*}
Thus, the ordered pair $(1, 3) \in f \circ h$.  Can you continue?